# Function-try-block for Lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

Is it possible using [Function-try-block](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block) on Lambda? if it's possible how we can use it?
I mean something like this:

```cpp
auto fooFunc = [] ()->bool try {return true;} catch(...) {return false};
```

return bool is just an example.